# A single vertex operator - bare bones explanation?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, vertex-algebras

There is an ocean of literature (and a sea of popular texts inside) on vertex algebras, including quite a lot of Q & A here on MO, and I am trying to read some random selections from time to time. I am not even sure whether I gradually do understand more or not.

In this question I decided to single out one of the simplest "building blocks" or "starting points" of the whole stuff, since I could not really find much about it.

My question is: how exactly shall I understand mathematically one separately taken vertex operator? What kind of object is it?

Very imprecisely and vaguely, I developed this kind of intuition: a vertex operator is an operator-valued distribution concentrated at a single point, i. e. an operator-valued delta-function. Is this correct?

Trying to be more specific - maybe we are given some kind of geometric substrate, like some manifold, say; a vertex operator is like a delta-function on that manifold, with an operator $T$ at a single point $x$ of this manifold and nothing else elsewhere. Now, by analogy with a "usual" delta-function, which can be viewed as a functional assigning to functions $f$ the values $f(x)$, we might think that a vertex operator is a functional assigning to... here begins something that I am not sure about:

- assigning to sections $s$ of some vector bundle the results of action $T(s(x))$;
- or assigning to vector bundles $E$ operators acting on the fibres $E_x$;
- or...?

Does the above viewpoint make sense at all? Can it be made more rigorous?

The only place that I could find where singled out vertex operators are discussed at length is chapter 13 in Pressley & Segal's "Loop groups", where these operators are also called blips and are described in terms of $L\mathbb T$, the group of (smooth? analytic?) self-maps of the group $\mathbb T=\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ with pointwise group structure: if $L\mathbb T$ acts on some Hilbert space $\mathscr H$, they define the operator $\psi_x$ on $\mathscr H$, for $x\in\mathbb T$, as the one that corresponds to the limit of actions of those self-maps which make one complete roundtrip in a neighborhood of $x$ and are identity elsewhere.

Vaguely this indeed resembles delta-functions. Can this be reformulated in terms of functional view of delta-functions as above?

If my intuition is just not relevant - what is the correct one?

Comment: It's not clear to me upon reading your question whether you already understand what vertex \[operator\] *algebras* are and are trying to understand what vertex *operators* are, or whether you're trying to understand vertex algebras in the first place. It's possible to understand (and rigorously define) the algebras in a purely formal / algebraic way without trying to care about what the operators actually "are".

Comment: Have you looked at: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Vertex_operator ?

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Well I cannot say I understand V[O]As but I agree that it is possible to do this without ever mentioning vertex operators. But this question is precisely about the latter - I hope to grasp the algebraic side better if I will have some tangible images in mind like analogy with delta distributions

Comment: @S.Carnahan No I have not seen this before, thank you! The entry indeed contains lots of densely packed information and several very important references. However it is, I think, packed a bit too densely. As for the references, if I understand correctly, the key ones are Corrigan & Fairlie, Date-Kashiwara-Miwa, and Fubini-Veneziano, is that correct?

Comment: In any case it would be great if you (or anybody else) would provide an answer based on your link but shifted more towards the vertex operators per se...